# Array of object length not detected in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, typescript, object

I have an array of objects which name is tagTagfilter. When I console.log it in the browser, it didn't check the length value inside it right away.

```
tagTagFilter: TagFilter = {
        filterName: 'Tag',
        tags: []
    };
```

[image]

the value is there, but the length is still 0. I already check it with tagTagFilter.length but it still shows zero. How to solve this? I am using typescript

Comment: It should not matter to you so much, the gold standard to check the length of the array should be `tagTagFilter.tags.length()` this should give you an accurate result in any point of time & if you are scared about it causing a problem, write an `if` condition to protect your code.

Comment: yep i have tried that and it still shows zero

Comment: can you provide more context for investigation? and if a deadline is close, use an `if` condition to protect your code.

Comment: Set a timeout and check, to your console

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the fist time you console.log TagFilter, the "tags" was  empty. Then "tags" is pushed to push the new values.
"This value evaluated upon fist expanding. It may changed since then."
[Heare is example for you](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZPMPd.png)

Answer (score 0):

console.table(tagTagFilter);
it will show the value of array in a table format. Much better than console.log for array cases.

Comment: That's not the point of it. The problem is it didn't detect the array length

Answer (score 0):

Try using
“ tagTagFilter.tags.length ”